# Identifying which logical core is hyperthreaded and which one is not

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have this info from /proc/cpuinfo (shown below). My question is which core is hyperthreaded here. Secondly, which core lies on which processor, as there are two quad core processors here, as it is a dual socket system with 8 cores in total.

I interpret this as, core 0, 2, 4 and 6 are the 4 physical cores in processor 1, while core 1, 3, 5 and 7 are the 4 physical cores on processor 0. Cores 9-15 are the hyperthreaded ones. Is my interpretation correct?

```
-bash-3.2$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id'
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 0
-bash-3.2$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'
core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 1
core id         : 1
core id         : 2
core id         : 2
core id         : 3
core id         : 3
core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 1
core id         : 1
core id         : 2
core id         : 2
core id         : 3
core id         : 3
-bash-3.2$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'processor'
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
processor       : 4
processor       : 5
processor       : 6
processor       : 7
processor       : 8
processor       : 9
processor       : 10
processor       : 11
processor       : 12
processor       : 13
processor       : 14
processor       : 15
```

Comment: Asking which core is hyperthreaded is like asking which of two brothers born at the same time is the twin. All CPUs on the same core are equal.

Comment: Gabe, I concur with you.

Comment: Gabe, the only possible question here: what pairs of virtual processors share the physical core and physical die (socket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is just to benchmark it.

Write any trivial program that uses 2 threads. Then bind the threads to two cores.
If the performance drops significantly between a pair of cores versus another pair, then you know those two cores are on the same physical core.

I would trust a benchmark like this over whatever anything else tells you.

In Windows, the logical/physical cores are interleaved.
Cores 0,1 are on the same physical core.
Cores 2,3 are on the same...
Cores 4,5 are on the same... etc...

It may be different on Linux.

Comment: Yes, mystical I have also tried that and the results support my interpretation.

Comment: Benchmarking this way is not reliable if the machine has some other unrelated load which is being run on the same cores.

Comment: MetallicPriest, you benchmark was a macro (fluidanimate) and it was different code when using different thread number. Try to use a simpler benchmark with 2 threads; no difference in code. E.g. do the barrier in a loop.

Comment: osgx, I also tried with other benchmarks from PARSEC and yes all the results support my interpretation. In Linux CPU 0-7 are physical ones while 8-15 are hyperthreads. In Windows, its just like what u said, that is CPU 0,1 is one core.

Comment: You should not to run a large (macro) bechmark to find HT-relations between cores. You should run microbenchmark on pair-to-pair basis.

Comment: The benchmark results doesn't support anything, and it is ONLY your interpretation of the results. It may be wrong. I think, better way of finding it will be a learning Linux Kernel sources and its HT-enumerator (it works via [APCI, which sees HT cores](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/arch/x86/kernel/acpi/boot.c#L1284)). Also, read the kernel boot logs (`dmesg`).

Answer (score 3):

Can you post `dmesg` results from boot? They should contain description of coreids:

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c#L493

```
 493        if (!printed && (c->x86_max_cores * smp_num_siblings) > 1) {
 494                printk(KERN_INFO  "CPU: Physical Processor ID: %d\n",
 495                       c->phys_proc_id);
 496                printk(KERN_INFO  "CPU: Processor Core ID: %d\n",
 497                       c->cpu_core_id
```

Another variant is to use `hwloc`: http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/

It was created to dig out topology of any system. Example of normal system:

[image: Example of topology in graphic form]

And it will represent [HT-cores:](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.2.1/#cli_examples)

[image: Example of HT-topology in graphic form]

Output from this utility can be in text format, in xml format, rendered.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable Hyperthreading, *all* processors become virtual.  There are no purely physical processors.  As [Raymond Chen explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/12/16/504659.aspx):

> When you turn on hyperthreading, each individual physical processor
>   acts as if it were two virtual processors. ... The two virtual
>   processors associated with each physical processor are completely
>   equivalent. It's not like one is physical and one is virtual. They are
>   both virtual and compete equally for a share of the one physical CPU.
>   When you set processor affinities, you set them to virtual processors.

Comment: We know, but naming them "physical" and "virtual" is just an easy way identify which pairs are together.

Answer (score 0):

To address only the question of how to interpret `/proc/cpuinfo`: a hyperthreaded pair can be identified by picking out "processor" entries that have the same values for `cpu id` and for `core id`.

So in the output provided in the original question, processor 0 and processor 8 are a hyperthreaded pair, as are 1 & 9, and 2 & 10, etc.